# How to protect library from getting uninstalled on CentOS6

Tags: centos, yum, centos6

I want to protect certain core libraries like **sshd, cronnie** from getting uninstalled accidentally or intentionally.

Recently one our developer accidentally deleted **cronnie** by uninstalling **sendmail** library.

Now we want to avoid such incidents from happening again.

Comment: How about not giving admin access to a "developer"? :-)

Comment: @DanilaVershinin we are very small team of 3-4 devs who work as full stack. So each one can potentially be responsible for maintaining libraries (install/uninstall) based on load. Hence there is no point implementing access control at this point of time